# Perl Multi-Dimensional Hash to Pretty Table

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, hashtable

I've been at this a few days now with no success. I have a hash with two dimensions which I'm hoping to create a table out of.

Here is an example of the hash dump:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'bill' => {
                   'deploy_status' => 'checked',
                   'bill_acceptance' => 'checked',
                   'daily_status' => '',
                   'awareness' => 'checked',
                   'aar_summary' => 'checked',
                   'daily_snapshot' => ''
                 },
      'hillary' => {
                      'deploy_status' => 'checked',
                      'bill_acceptance' => 'checked',
                      'daily_status' => 'checked',
                      'awareness' => 'checked',
                      'aar_summary' => '',
                      'daily_snapshot' => 'checked'
                    },
      'george' => {
                   'deploy_status' => 'checked',
                   'bill_acceptance' => 'checked',
                   'daily_status' => '',
                   'awareness' => 'checked',
                   'aar_summary' => 'checked',
                   'daily_snapshot' => 'checked'
                 },
      'laura' => {
                        'deploy_status' => '',
                        'bill_acceptance' => 'checked',
                        'daily_status' => 'checked',
                        'awareness' => '',
                        'aar_summary' => 'checked',
                        'daily_snapshot' => ''
                      }
    };
```

You might have notice that the last value defined will eventually denote whether or not an input check box is checked or not.

My eventual data *should* look like the following.. will all of the templates secondary hash keys completed.

```
<div class="user-table add-bottom sortable" >
    <div class="user-table-header">
        <div class="user-table-cell"> &nbsp; </div>
        <div class="user-table-cell">Bill</div>
        <div class="user-table-cell">Hillary</div>
        <div class="user-table-cell">George</div>
        <div class="user-table-cell">Laura</div>
    </div>

    <div class="user-table-row">
        <div class="user-table-cell">AAR Summary</div>
        <div class="user-table-cell"> <input type="checkbox" name="bill-aar_summary" checked> </div>
        <div class="user-table-cell"> <input type="checkbox" name="hillary-aar_summary"> </div>
        <div class="user-table-cell"> <input type="checkbox" name="george-aar_summary" checked> </div>
        <div class="user-table-cell"> <input type="checkbox" name="laura-aar_summary" checked> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="user-table-row">
        <div class="user-table-cell">Daily Snapshot</div>
        <div class="user-table-cell"> <input type="checkbox" name="bill-daily_snapshot"> </div>
        <div class="user-table-cell"> <input type="checkbox" name="hillary-daily_snapshot" checked> </div>
        <div class="user-table-cell"> <input type="checkbox" name="george-daily_snapshot" checked> </div>
        <div class="user-table-cell"> <input type="checkbox" name="laura-daily_snapshot"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my code to find all the values of %subscription:

```
print $html->tableOpen();
print $html->tableHeaderOpen();

foreach my $friend(sort keys %subscription) {

    if ( $fCount == $lastFriend ) {
        print $html->tableHead($friend); print $html->tableHeadClose;
    }
    else { print $html->tableHead($friend); } 

    foreach my $template (sort keys %{ $subscription{$friend}}) {       
        print $html->tableRowStart();

        print $html->tableCellOpen . $html->checkBox($subscription{$friend}{$template}); . $html->tableCellClose();

        print $html->tableRowClose();
    }
}

print $html->tableClose();
```

Although everytime I print an input box, I'm printing a new table row and I know I'm getting lost in my for loops.

Example:

```
...
<div class="user-table-row">
    <div class="user-table-cell">Daily Snapshot</div>
    <div class="user-table-cell"> <input type="checkbox" name="bill-daily_snapshot"> </div>
</div>
...
<div class="user-table-row">
    <div class="user-table-cell">Daily Snapshot</div>
    <div class="user-table-cell"> <input type="checkbox" name="hillary-daily_snapshot"> </div>
</div>
```

How can I accomplish this period? Is there a better way to go about it?

Comment: what do you want to determine the order (Bill, Hillary, George, Laura)?

Comment: Alphabetical would be preferred. Unless you mean something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest your loops like this (disclaimer: not tested!). I'd also add another hash to store the friendly names of the templates:

```
my %key_names = {
    'deploy_status' => 'Deploy Status',
    'bill_acceptance' => 'Bill Acceptance',
    'daily_status' => 'Daily Status',
    'awareness' => 'Awareness',
    'aar_summary' => 'AAR summary',
    'daily_snapshot' => 'Daily Snapshot'
};

print $html->tableOpen();

# Header
print $html->tableHeaderOpen();
foreach my $friend(sort keys %subscription) {
    print $html->tableHead($friend);
}
print $html->tableHeadClose;

# Rows
foreach my $template (sort keys %key_names) {       
    print $html->tableRowStart();
    print $html->tableCell($key_names{$template});
    foreach my $friend(sort keys %subscription) {
        print $html->tableCellOpen . $html->checkBox($subscription{$friend}{$template}); . $html->tableCellClose();
    }
    print $html->tableRowClose();
}

print $html->tableClose();
```